# How to detect a cycle in a graph implemented as a linked list?

Tags: java, graph, linked-list

I have a graph implemented as a doubly linked list using java.util.LinkedList.  Basically, each node on the linked list is a vertex of the graph, and each of those vertices are connected to other linked lists to represent the edges.  I'm asked to use the following algorithm to detect a cycle in the graph.

```
DFS-Cycle (u)
Precondition: u is a vertex in a graph G
Postcondition: a cycle reachable from u is returned, of one exists
    color[u] <- RED
    push u onto stack
    for each v in Adj[u] //explore edge (u,v)
        if color[v] = RED//back edge
            return list of elements on stack
        else if color[v] = BLACK
            DFS-Cycle(v)
    colour[u] <- GRAY
    pop u from stack
```

I do not understand the part where you have to connect the linked list graph to an array called "color" and assign colors as you traverse the list.  I'm not permitted to change the node structure of the linked lists (Basically the whole graph).  I'm only allowed to implement the cycle method to detect a cycle in the graph and return a boolean.  The method takes a Node as an argument.  Can someone please guide me on how to begin with?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What is the structure of your graph Node? Does it have an id?

Comment: @Tudor: The node is an object type and stores a number (int) and a list (linked list). Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

`color` would a *map* that is used for marking nodes - if a node `v` is found to be marked with color RED (`if color[v] = RED`) then it means that that node has already been visited, and a cycle has been found.

Comment: Can you explain how to create a map using the same nodes in the linked list?

Comment: `Map<Node, String> colors = new HashMap<Node, String>();` assuming that the "color" is being represented with string constants, if not, replace with the appropriate data type.